# js not working properly on page which is loaded by jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I am new to jquery and can't even assume how deeply this issue can go.
When the external page (in this case shop.php) is loaded into index.php, by Jquery function .load(); , it falls apart. Many jquery commands and plugins, that are applied to the shop.php page, aren't working.
This confuses me, because some of js commands and plugins still works. Obviously i can't say that files are not loaded completely, just majority of them are not working.

When I paste shop.php content into index.php, it works perfect. Also when i add desired js code into shop.php (wrapped into script tag), it works as well.

I really don't expect from anyone to look deeply into this problem. I just wanna know if this is common issue, and is there simple explanation for it ? 
If not i'll seek for some different approach.

My code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.touchcarousel-1.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ddslick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/top-navigation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="top-bar"><?php include("top-bar.php"); ?></div>

<div id="pageWraper"><?php include("home.php"); ?></div>



</body>

</html>
```

top-bar.php

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="navigationWraper">
    <li><a href="home.php" class="menuLink">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Services</a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>asdasd</li>
        <li>asdasdas</li>
        <li>derwer</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="shop.php" class="menuLink">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

shop.php

```
<div id="shop">
<div id="shopheader">
  <div id="shopitemstop">
    <div id="productcat">

          <!-- bunch of code -->

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
    $("a.menuLink").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#pageWraper").load(this.href);

    });
});

});
```

Hope this helps

Thanks,

**Update :**

I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("js/shop.js");
    $.getScript("js/jquery.touchcarousel-1.2.js");
    $.getScript("js/main.js");

});
</script>
```

on top of shop.php page, dont know how right this is, but its working now. 
Only thing that bugs me is if i remove jquery.touchcarousel-1.2.js from index.php head, page falls apart. It is like, only working if both of them are loaded ????

Comment: you need to make sure your jQuery version uses .live insted of .bind as default try anything that is for the content of shop.php if it using `.click(fn)`/`.mouseover(fn)`/`.mouseout(fn)`... anything like that try `.live('click', fn)`/`.live('mouseover', fn)`/`.live('mouseout', fn)` see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: At least some of the plugins you are using will not cope with dynamically loaded content. Far too many plugins only work on the initial DOM elements when they are run. You often need to re-run the plugins after loading content.

Comment: Also, as `Zephram` *almost* points out below, you are nesting two document ready handlers. Although this will not actually affect the outcome.

Comment: The JavaScript does not work because the content is not there when the script expects it. That shop code needs to work on dynamic content. Not knowing what this "shop.js" code is, it is impossible to help other than saying what the issue is.

Comment: ... or be run again after the content is loaded

Comment: You should initialize you plugins again after the .load()

Comment: @MartinBarker `.live()` **is deprecated**. Use `.on()` with event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:**

> I really don't expect from anyone to look deeply into this problem. I
>   just wanna know if this is common issue, and is there simple
>   explanation for it ?

**Answer:**

Yes, it is a common problem for Ajax/dynamically loaded content.

The cause is: that most plugins work on the DOM *as it exists when the plugin is run* (unless they were specifically created to work with dynamic content).

The fixes include:

- Find another plugin that is tolerant of dynamic content
- Re-run the plugins
- Strip out existing plugins and re-run the plugins (takes some effort to figure out some plugins)
- Don't load content dynamically for plugins that do not support it

Comment: Thanks for information TrueBlueAussie, looks like i'm going back to drawing table.